# Javascript variable not able to display in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Take a look at my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile App Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: some secret api key
  authorize: true
</script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/css/jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5b1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadData() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl","headline"])
    .result(function(result) {
      profile = result.values[0];
/*
      profHTML = "<p><a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
      profHTML += "<img class=img_border align=\"left\" src=\"" + profile.pictureUrl + "\"></a>";     
      profHTML += "<a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
      profHTML += "<h2 class=myname>" + profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName + "</a> </h2>";
      profHTML += "<span class=myheadline>" + profile.headline + "</span>";
*/
        profHTML = profile.id;
        //alert(profHTML); alerts the id
      //$("#profile").html(profHTML);
    });
}

</script>

</head>
<body class="yui3-skin-sam  yui-skin-sam">

<script>alert(profHTML);</script> <!-- Does not alert anything-->
<div id="profile">
    </div>  
    <script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="loadData"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to capture the profile id in the HTML file , but unable to do that . How can I display it in the HTML file ? And why my code is not working . Please help

Comment: you are trying to write out that variable before you call that function which assign its value? "alert(profHTML);" this is wrong and results in js error because profHTML is nothing... so it crashes and alert doesnt even show up.

Comment: Ok. So is there any way I can alert in HTML ?

Comment: alert is ok, but you must initialize your variable before alerting it... Oh, and you must definitely declare the variable outside that function to use it in alert...

Comment: @Gatekeeper why  alert(profHTML) is wrong ?

Comment: because when you call that alert, "profHTML" holds no value and it is not even a variable declared... you have it declared only inside that function. If you add "var profHTML = "";" before your function, alert will show up but will be empty because variable value is not filled yet. [explanation](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltut07.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . So there is no way I can alert the value of id from my HTML ?

Comment: there is, but you must declare it outside function, then call the function to fill in some value and THEN call the alert... I dont know what that JQuerry code is supposed to do, but when i simplify your example: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pcKZv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create element with `id='profile'` and uncomment `$("#profile").html(profHTML);` line. `$("#profile").html(profHTML)` is one of jQuery's the ways to 'alert' to HTML.

**UPDATE:** have you tried uncommenting `$("#profile").html(profHTML);`? If yes, did you get any errors?

**UPDATE 2:** if you need to get those var out of the function, you can do the following:

```
var my_var = null;
function loadData() {
    //.....
    profHTML = profile.id;
    my_var = profHTML;
    //.....
}
```

If not - I can't understand what do you want to do with that variable. Please explain further. :)

**UPDATE 3:** There are two options:

1. Do an AJAX request to your backend and save cookie. See [JQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery.cookie](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)
2. Write that value to a hidden input in the login form, so this value will be submitted to your backend on form submit.

   `jQuery('#hidden').val(profile.id);
   //....somewhere in html....//
   <form> <!--your login form -->
   <input type='hidden' id='hidden' value=''>
   <!-- some other html -->
   </form>`

Comment: @JOHN actually I need to create a session of the id . For that I need the value of profile id .

Comment: @JOHN It was uncommented earlier and I get the value . No errors . But I need the value say in a variable

Comment: @JOHN It alerts null !! . I need to create a session of that profile id, of course by using PHP script

Comment: So you need to pass that var from JS to PHP somehow?

Comment: yes . exactly . But from within the same file so that after successful login user can be redirected to my website

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong scope of the variable. If you declare it outside of the function first, I think it will work.